# JMETER: getting unicode in response

Tags: jmeter

My jmeter response is as:

```
  {"result":"fail", "reason":"\u0027radius\u0027 should be greater than 0 and less than 90000"}
```

I want to assert response but \u0027 is a garbage value and I want to discard those value in jmeter response. I tried changing the unicode value in jmeter.properties file but it didn't help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I open jmeter from command line using : jmeter -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 and i found file.encoding=UTF-8 in debug sampler but the response is still same: "reason":"\u0027radius\u0027 should be greater than 0 and less than 90000"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\u0027` is not "garbage", it's [apostrophe character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/27/index.htm) so it might be a bug in your application. Moreover, apostrophe doesn't need escaping according to [JSON website](http://www.json.org/)

[image: JSON Escaping]

So I would recommend double checking the requirement.

In the meantime you still can "assert" the response as [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) in `Contains` and `Matches` modes treats input as a [regular expression](https://www.pcre.org/) so pattern doesn't have to be exact match, it could be a "match" in terms of regular expressions

And finally you can replace these unicode escapes with apostrophe signs using [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and code like:

```
def unicode = new String(prev.getResponseData())
log.info('Unicode: ' + unicode) 
def normal = unicode.replaceAll('\\\\u0027','\'')
log.info('Normal: ' + normal)
prev.setResponseData(normal, 'UTF-8')
```

It will replace all occurrences of `\u0027` with `'` in the response and substitute response data with the new value:

[image: JMeter Groovy Replace Value in Response]

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)